# performSegueWithIdentifier not firing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboardsegue

I have a view controller with a button that launches the twitter login page via `STTwitter`. The `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier`function return `NO` or `YES` depending on the isDoneTwitterLogin iVar.

In the function `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation`, 
I have the following code:

```
LoginViewController *loginViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Twitter Login"];
[loginViewController doneTwitterLogin:YES];
[loginViewController.navigationController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"User Info" sender:viewController];
```

The last line doesn't do anything. Neither does `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` get fired.

Anything I'm doing wrong? 
There is a segue in my storyboard from `LoginViewController` named "User Info".

UPDATE 1: The `LoginViewController` scene is embedded in a `UINavigationController`.
The segue "User Info" is connected to a `UIButton` in the `LoginViewController`scene. This is the new code I tried:

```
LoginViewController *loginViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Twitter Login"];
[loginViewController doneTwitterLogin:YES];
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:loginViewController];
NSLog(@"%@", loginViewController.navigationController);
[loginViewController.navigationController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"User Info" sender:loginViewController];
```

The previous code was returning a `(null)` navigation controller. The above code returns a valid `UINavigationController` object.

UPDATE 2: The above code generated an error message saying that the instance of UINavigationController didn't have a segue named "User Info". I have changed the line to the one below:

`[loginViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"User Info" sender:loginViewController];`

But this doesn't do anything either.

Comment: Where is the `performSegueWithIdentifier` code?  Here, you're calling the segue on a navigation controller.  As such, the methods you ask about would be called on the `UINavigationController`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I solved my issue. It had to do with saving the currently displayed view controller when the app goes to background and then perform the segue before the app goes active. And thanks for the downvote. Really makes me feel at home!

Answer (score 0):

`shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` is called on the view controller performing the segue.

In this case, the following line:

```
[loginViewController.navigationController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"User Info" sender:viewController];
```

In this case, the view controller we're calling this method on (and therefore the view controller we're asking to perform the segue) is the `loginViewController`'s `navigationController`.

It seems most likely to me that you have hooked up the segue from the `loginViewController` and that the `loginViewController` doesn't actually have a navigation controller (`loginViewController.navigationController` returns `nil`).  Otherwise, I imagine that this code would crash and you'd get a message telling you that `UINavigationController` has no segue by this name, etc.

Assuming everything on the storyboard is hooked up correctly, we probably just need to change how we're calling `performSegueWithIdentifier:` to something like this:

```
[loginViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"User Info" sender:viewController];
```

(If this doesn't make it work, then you're going to have to provide a lot more detail.)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a created a navigation controller on your storyboard and embeded `loginViewController` into it, then you dont need to create a new instance of the navigation controller.

```
LoginViewController *loginViewController = 
                          [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" 
                                                     bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]
                    instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Twitter Login"];
[loginViewController doneTwitterLogin:YES];
//perform segue from  login to user info controller.
[loginViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"User Info"
                                         sender:loginViewController ];
```

Comment: Ok I'll try that tomorrow and report my findings.

Comment: I get the error `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'User Info'. Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'`. I still get the error after reembedding the view controller in a uinavigationcontroller in the storyboard.